# Do Nyquist samples have the same sum as the integral of the signal?

Tags: nyquist

Assume I sample a signal according to the Nyquist criterion. Then I perform a simple summation / integral over a linearly interpolated signal. Is this equivalent to the integral over the continuous signal, i.e.?

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x(nT) T = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)\text{d}t$$

I hope my representation is correct for what I mean. My question relates to whether a reconstruction, e.g. Whittaker–Shannon interpolation, is necessary   in practical application. I would also appreciate any literature pointers for discussions on how this might affect practical cases with finite time and imperfect filters.

Comment: what is "$B$"?  is it the signal bandwidth.  is $T=\frac{1}{2B}$?  if so, the summation is a [Riemann summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) for the integral and they might come out close if $T$ is sufficiently small.  why not just say $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x(nT) \, T \approx \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t) \, \mathrm{d}t$$ ??

Comment: Yes, you are right. My question is whether the two are *equal* given the Nyquist criterion.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: As long as $T$ is chosen such that the sampling theorem is satisfied, the sum and the integral don't just come close, they're identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation in your question is correct. If we assume that $x(t)$ is an ideally band-limited signal with bandwidth $B$, then, according to the [sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem), we have

$$x(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x(nT)\frac{\sin\left[\pi (t-nT)/T\right]}{\pi (t-nT)/T}\tag{1}$$

where the sampling rate $1/T$ satisfies $1/T>2B$.

If we assume that the integral over $x(t)$ exists, using $(1)$ we obtain

$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)dt&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x(nT)\frac{\sin\left[\pi (t-nT)/T\right]}{\pi (t-nT)/T}dt\\&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x(nT)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left[\pi (t-nT)/T\right]}{\pi (t-nT)/T}dt\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\pi t/T)}{\pi t/T}dt\cdot \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x(nT)\\&=T\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x(nT)\tag{2}\end{align}$$

where the last equality follows from the fact that the integral in the one but last line just equals the DC value of an ideal low pass filter with gain $T$.